# getting "module initialization error" after deploying sls code from windows

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'am deploying lambda function from my office where i have ubuntu operating system. when i deploy my serverless code its works fine, i can access the lambda api without any problem . but same code when i deploy at my home machine where i have windows operating system there it showing error "module initialization error" at the time of accessing the  lambda api ("Note- There is no issues while deploying it, issue comes when i access the lambda API after deploying it from windows machine").

I debug the issue and i found that the issue is related with "bcrypt" Package. and in the logs i saw that, at the time when the code execution reaches to the file where i imported the "bcrypt" module it throws error. I don't know why it showing two different behavior on 2 different operating system for bcrypt only.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@serverless/fdk": "^0.7.1",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "serverless-http": "^2.0.2"
```

logs for myOwnFunction

```
module initialization error
Error
2019-06-08 09:25:06.043 (+05:30)        33f9015c-c9f0-43a5-8c4a-1fc617ad955d    inside OwnerModel
```

In my code when code execution reaches at the below line

```
import bcrypt from  'bcrypt';
```

It shows module initialization error

I expect to execute the lambda api even if it is deployed with the help of windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compile the `bcrypt` module on Amazon Linux with specific NodeJS version then zip and deploy it.

Alternatively, I would suggest use [`bcryptjs`](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js)